# i want to change language of app without restarting app

Tags: ios, swift

I need to have multiple languages facility in my app. I am able to change language with localization strings, but storyboard text are not changing without restarting app. I added Arabic language also for users that needs to change alignments of text as well which is also working fine if I restart app.

I am using AppleLanguages user default key to change language and localized strings for dynamic texts.

Comment: to be 100% sure i'm reloading view controllers by setting rootViewControll in appDelegate

Comment: @jitendra tanwar . Did u find final solution multilangague . Please help me

Comment: Yes i solved the issue by reloading rootview controller on langauge change . And if you want to change language from storyboard itself then please confirm if newly added views (label , button , etc)  is present in other language storyboard's string file or not . As we need to manually add all the view(label , button , etc) added after adding multiple languages in project.

Answer (score -1):

For Objective C :

```
+(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language{

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
{
   object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
});
objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

For Swift :

```
class func setLanguage(_ language: String) {
var onceToken: Int
if (onceToken == 0) {
        /* TODO: move below code to a static variable initializer (dispatch_once is deprecated) */
    object_setClass(Bundle.main, BundleEx.self)
}
    onceToken = 1
objc_setAssociatedObject(Bundle.main, bundle, language ? Bundle(path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: language, ofType: "lproj")) : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
}
```

Add the above method and just pass the language which you want to convert.

If you have added **ja.lproj** then send "**ja**" as a param to the above method.

This will convert Storyboard language without restart.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is bundleEx

Comment: Not clear enough, what is BundleEx? where is bundle object declared?